# Raspberry pi Flask CSS does not work I Don't Know Why

Tags: python, flask

Hi i am trying to host a server my raspberry pi with flask but css does not work. It shows plain html. when i try the same thing with same file names, location and same code it works but from my raspberry pi it does not work?

### To Fix I Tried (so don't bother saying):

- Tried using static or normal way
- Tried doing cmd+shift+R
- Tried changing file names

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>THD</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
    </head>
<html>
```

FLASK:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main_page():
    return render_template('learn.html')
```

TREE VIEW:

[image: tree view]

Thank You So Much If You Can Fix It.

Comment: @jmoerdyk alright sorry also thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 0):

turns out i have made a typo i didnt notice it for hours my  looked like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=""{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>THD</title>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "static/styles.css">
    </head>
<html>
```

You have to call the relative path to the css file

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styles.css/">
```

You need to get out to templates folder with .. and then put path to styles.css

Hope this helps!